# count the number of an array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, counter

I want to get the count of each element of an array. I am using postgres.
I have array [1,2,3,1,1,2]. How to compare these array elements against each elements.

**the output would be:**

**array_element** | **count**

---

1 | 3

2 | 2

3 | 1

Answer (score 1):

You could use `unnest`:

```
SELECT array_elem, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM t, unnest(c) s(array_elem)
GROUP BY array_elem
ORDER BY array_elem;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=93441928fa378c878979514f94c59b0b)**

Comment: What happens if the array is dynamic? how will the table is constructed in 
SELECT '{1,2,3,1,1,2}'::int[] AS c?

& what is the purpose of s(array_elem)?

Answer (score 1):

To apply to a single value (not a table column):

```
SELECT i, count(*) AS cnt
FROM   unnest('{1,2,3,1,1,2}'::int[]) i
GROUP  BY i
ORDER  BY i;
```

[`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) is a set-returning function, a.k.a. "table function". You can basically use it like a table in a `SELECT` query.